# How to add DLL's to C++ program (to access SQL database)

Tags: c++, sql, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to use a C++ program to access a mySQL database on my localhost.

However I'm getting an error that I think is related to either a missing dll or a missing .lib file but I don't know how to add them?

I'm using the files/libraries from the mySQL Connector C++ 8.0 download.

Specifically how do I add the .dll files to my project to stop these errors?v

See below my current code!
Any help or suggestions would be fantastic, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

        sql::Driver* driver;
        sql::Connection* con;
        sql::Statement* stmt;
        sql::ResultSet* res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "password");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("test");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    }
```

The errors I'm getting are:

````
1>------ Build started: Project: AccessSQL_v1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>accessSQL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>accessSQL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QEAA@QEBD@Z) referenced in function main
1>accessSQL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __cdecl sql::SQLString::asStdString(void)const " (__imp_?asStdString@SQLString@sql@@QEBAAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class sql::SQLString const &)" (??6std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@AEBVSQLString@sql@@@Z)
1>accessSQL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_get_driver_instance referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\LabPC\source\repos\AccessSQL_v1\x64\Debug\AccessSQL_v1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "AccessSQL_v1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== ```
````

Comment: Did you get an import library `.lib` file?  If so, you need to add it to the project.

Comment: I have a folder with 4 .dll files in it, and 6 .lib files, I've added the lib directories but I don't know how to add the .dll files to the project, that's the crux of my question. How do I add the dlls to the project?

Comment: You don't use dll files as part of the build, only the corresponding .lib file. Those get passed to the linker. If using windows-based compilers (as seems likely from your saying DLL file rather than SO) you can also use #pragma comment(lib, "libfilename.lib") within the source code rather than needing to alter your build settings directly. Unless you pass fully qualified file names as part of #pragma comment(lib, "...") you will still need to alter your linker settings to add the path where the lib files can be found.

Comment: The dlls need to be in one of the folders of the `PATH` environment variable or the same folder as the executable when executing your program. They are not part of the build process with Visual Studio. Instead you link to the import libraries.

Comment: SoronelHaetir your advice to not worry about the DLL and include the lib files, using ```#pragma comment(lib, "libfilename.lib")``` working perfectly! Thank you so much! Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct solution please?

Comment: @JoelGray Just to add -- the only time you need to worry about the DLL's is when your application is actually running.  As others mentioned, building an application doesn't require those DLL's to even exist.

Comment: Ah ha I see! That makes sense! Thanks PaulMcKenzie!